# UI5 Application not loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an `UI5` application that opens in every other browser other than IE.

It shows:

```
SCRIPT1005: Expected '('
ui5loader-dbg.js (1421,5)
```

I am not entirely sure what might be the cause, since there are few other applications which are loading fine. Is this related to stricter policies in IE? If so, how do i bypass it?

Comment: Can you share IE version and Windows version with patch level?

Comment: It's IE11, and I am testing on Windows 10.

Comment: This is impossible to figure out without seeing all of your code. You have used some JS syntax in one of your controls or controllers that IE does not like. Are you using jslint/jshint?

Comment: You can paste your source code here https://jshint.com/ and disable "New JS Features (ES6)" in the configuration. You probably used some new syntax which IE11 doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Browser has their own js engine and functions. Some functions can be working differently. For example IE has policy for strict mode. Also some browsers can run faulty js code. You can try below options:

- Check js code is formal. You can use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to identify the error.
- Use [Polyfill](https://polyfill.io/v3/) tool for completing browser compatibility.

Comment: I tried this already, and have manually checked as well. All the parenthesis are fine. When i try to load the standalone application in IE i get this error. 

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected '('

at execModule (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:95:1397)

Should I try changing the UI5 version? I don't think my code is causing the problems.

Comment: If you can create public sample for us, may be we can see the error.

Comment: My file is 2700 lines long, so jslint or jshint were unable to parse completely. Moreover I have already the polyfill.js included.